# Baking from high poly gives unexpected results

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

When I tried to bake my high poly to my low poly I followed every step of the tutorial online. But the image just doesn't appear like it should. I've also tried shuffling with the ray distance from 0.0 to 0.001 to 0.5 and even 12....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the tutorial you were watching?

Comment: please share your objects so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

On high poly object go through any modifier that may affect the baking and turn them off for render like this:

[image]

In addition, make sure you follow this steps too posted here:
[High Poly to Low poly normal bake looks weird](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190286/high-poly-to-low-poly-normal-bake-looks-weird/190295#190295)